# jqmobi data-refresh-ajax="true"

Tags: html, reload, jqmobi

I am trying to reload the content of a panel with  data-refresh-ajax="true" but it doesn't work.
The content is simple HTML and some JavaScript Variables / consts which I write with "document.write(NavHome);"
Can someone help me, whats wrong?

Best Regards
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

The kitchen sink, included in the github download, has a sample that shows how to use it.
If you click "jqUi" -> "Load External Content" you will see the random number gets updated each time.

```
<a href="kitchensink/external.html" data-persist-ajax="true" data-refresh-ajax="true" data-pull-scroller="true">Load External Content</a>
```